# Fade dynamic background image?

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have an AngularJS frontend with several divs with dynamically set background images. I set the images like this:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(path/to/image/' + imageFile + ')'}">
```

I would like to fade this image from and to a neutral white background color on a corresponding mouse enter/leave event.

I know I can do this using CSS3 transitions. But I only know how to do this with a background image that is statically defined in the corresponding CSS3 class. How do I do this with a dynamic background image?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `background-image` is already set as the "normal" state, and you won't mess up with that, maybe you can try a reverse `hover` effect, using the `:not` pseudo.

Set the transition to the div, and create a `:not(:hover)` selector, forcing the `background` to be white, if is not hovered... So when you hover it, it will fade into your background.

```
div#myDiv {
    transition: 1s;
}

div#myDiv:not(:hover) {
    background: white !important;
}
```

Just an idea... Hope it helps.

Comment: It did not, unfortunately... I've put this effect aside for the time being. Thanks anyway!